# Can GLPK be interrupted?

Tags: c, glpk, keyboardinterrupt

Does GLPK provide a means to safely interrupt a computation?

Suppose that the solver is run in a GUI application, within the same process. The user might decide that it is taking too long and want to interrupt the process.  Is there a way to do this cleanly without having to run GLPK in a separate process?

I do not need any solution returned when the computation is interrupted. I just want a clean stop (no memory leaks or broken state affecting future computations). I would specifically want to interrupt `glp_intopt()`.

---

**Update:**

`glp_intopt()` takes a callback function, and it appears that calling `glp_iop_terminate()` from within this callback function can signal the need to terminate to the solver. However, this seems to affect only the integer optimization stage. `glp_intopt()` may spend a very long time in solving the LP relaxation. It is still unclear to me if there is a way to interrupt this stage on demand.

Comment: Does this help?  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Error_handling

Comment: Though, at a glance, you would probably be better off just forking a child process to run GLPK in. There's nothing inherently bad with that approach, it is often just extra hassle. But in case of GLPK, running it in the same process with GUI might be even *more* hassle in the long run. You don't even have to restart the process it seems, you can interrupt the calculation with signal. Managing that with separate process will just be easier, than with a GUI framework in the same process.

Comment: @hyde Thanks for the comments. I'm not sure how I would use the error handling functionality to check for an interrupt. What I have isn't actually a GUI but a library usable from several high-level languages. It is typically used interactively (think Jupyter notebook or similar). Interruptibility is essential for interactive work. Running the solver in a separate process is too heavyweight, and would not be acceptable for this project.